# Split Address Column

Tags: excel, split, range, vba

I need to take an Excel Database that has an Address column setup like:
  "Physical Address, Mailing Address, Suit#; City; ST; Zip"  into columns split by the semi-colon.

Unfortunately I have data inside the Address column that has ASCII character references that isn't allowing me to just use "Text to Columns" so I developed the following code, but it doesn't do what I am wanting it to do.  The range I am splitting is in Column B.

```
Sub SplitAddress()
    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Address As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Row As Range
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    txt = ActiveCell.Value
    Address = Split(txt, "; ")

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Rng = Range("B3:B" & LastRow)

    j = 1

    For Each Row In Rng.Rows
        For i = 0 To UBound(Address)
            Cells(3, j + 1).Value = Address(i)
        Next i
    Next Row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Sub SplitAddress()
    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Address As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Range
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("B3:B" & LastRow)
    For Each R In Rng
        txt = R.Value
        Address = Split(txt, "; ")
        j = R.Row
        For i = 0 To UBound(Address)
            Cells(j, i + 3).Value = Address(i)
        Next i
    Next R
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**:

Better to make **i, j, LastRow Long** rather than **integer**:

```
Sub SplitAddress()
    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Address As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("B3:B" & LastRow)
    For Each R In Rng
        txt = R.Value
        Address = Split(txt, "; ")
        j = R.Row
        For i = 0 To UBound(Address)
            Cells(j, i + 3).Value = Address(i)
        Next i
    Next R
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2**:

This version moves the result to the **left** and thus over-writes column **B**:

```
Sub SplitAddress()
    ' version #3 - overwrites column B
    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Address As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Range
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("B3:B" & LastRow)
    For Each R In Rng
        txt = R.Value
        Address = Split(txt, "; ")
        j = R.Row
        For i = 0 To UBound(Address)
            Cells(j, i + 2).Value = Address(i)
        Next i
    Next R
End Sub
```

Comment: Right after it runs the 'Last Row = Active...'

Comment: Still getting the OverFlow Error... @ the same place
Here is the range of Column B = (B3:B1040000)

Comment: Change **LastRow** to **Long** as well.